# View the whole world with Open Layers map?

Tags: openlayers

My map is initialized as:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: this.mapService.getMapLayers(),
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
    zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 0,
  })
});
```

Div map is styled with css:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
```

But I am still not able to see the whole world [180,-180, 90, -90] and to zoom below level 3 on my screen.

Comment: To see the whole world along both axes at the same time you will need `multiWorld: true` in the view options.  See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v6.0.0/changelog/v6.0.0.md#the-view-is-constrained-so-only-one-world-is-visible

Comment: @Mike thanks a lot, it worked!